# nag complains about \centerline in environment "shaded" from package framed

Tags: horizontal-alignment, framed, warnings, nag

Running this with Miktex, pdflatex, Windows, TeXnicCenter, everything fully up to date:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{lightgray}

\begin{document}

\begin{shaded}
  Foo Bar
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

gives:

```
Package nag Warning: Command \centerline is TeX. 
(nag)                Use \centering or center environment instead on input line 13.
```

Is there anything I can do about it without changing the package itself? Any better packages than framed available that can do the same (page breaking colored boxed)? If not, how to contact the author of the package and inform him?

Comment: Time to check out [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I don't know much about the `framed` package, but @percusse has a good point: `mdframed` works very nicely and also handles page breaks.

Comment: @FooBar Another way is to avoid `nag` altogether. In my opinion it breaks more than it fixes.

Comment: For me, up until now, nag helped more than it made wrong/senseless suggestions. So, for the time beeing I'd rather keep it. Especially because I sometimes have to work on very old latex documents written by several people (that can be annoying sometimes, I tell you ;) )...

Comment: @foobar: the nag complaint is wrong, anyway -- it says \centerline is tex, but it is in fact Plain TeX (i.e., not a primitive)

Comment: Thanks, nice to know. But anyways, mdframed made everything better, so I can completly avoid the "problem" now and be more flexible. ;)

Comment: @FooBar I wrote a [paper for TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-3/tb84gregorio.pdf) about some horrible things people can do with LaTeX. There you might find something you'd never expect. `;-)`

Comment: The `amsbook` class is also somewhat incompatible with `nag`.  See [this post](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2012-September/019682.html) and subsequent discussion on that list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since nobody gave an answer, but only comments, I'll write the answer myself from the comments.

1. `nag` complain is <s>wrong</s> fussy
2. `mdframed` is more flexible than `framed` and doesn't produce this warning

Comment: `nag` is not really wrong, but only too fussy.